# Creating a ZeroMQ setup with many requesters and many repliers with a single router and dealer

Tags: node.js, zeromq

How do I create this setup, I want to be able to have many/one requester(s) which connects to one router which then connects to a single dealer and which in turn connects to multiple repliers all performing different tasks, now I want to be able to go a single replier from a requester for a particular task and get response, following examples from [Building Distributed Systems with Node.js and ØMQ](https://github.com/jimbojw/node-zmq-talk)  and i see he has bound the simple replier forked to a dealer, do make a dealer for each replier or do I make many repliers communicating to a single dealer. Kindly help, am still new to this, thanks.

Comment: You described what you *want*, so if you know what you want - why do you need help? There are many examples on how to use ZMQ with various languages, it's unclear what you need help with.

Comment: @Mjh i have successfully connected to one rep, now i want to have multiple rep (this is what i want now) how do i go about it?

Comment: am trying to make a microservices app using zmq, thats what am trying to achieve @Mjh

Comment: It appears you didn't read the guide fully, and it's lengthy guide.